# How to make position fixed with sticky component? Only works in Chrome and not working in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-position

I have a simple CSS layout with a sticky header, content, and footer. Inside the sticky header, I have a fixed element, which works in Chrome but not in Firefox, Safari etc

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container-header">
      <div>
         Some thing
      </div>
      <div class="fixed">Shoud be fixed but it scrolls in firefox, safari</div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">main</div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  padding: 1%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}

.header {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  background: #30b298;
}

.container-header {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 40%;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 2000px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee 0%,#B7EAE0 100%);
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/RutulPatel7077/pen/YzOGqvE
[image]

It is not working with Firefox. It looks sticky until you re-size the window or scroll down.

[image]

Comment: this worked for me on firefox

Comment: the codepen works fine for me on chrome, safari and firefox. if you can't get the codepen to reproduce the problem, then include a link to a webpage which does reproduce the problem